# Is there any way to integrate local hadoop with jenkins?

Tags: hadoop, jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I am new to jenkins. I am trying to integrate hadoop with jenkins.
My hadoop is running on port : 54310.

So when i installed hadoop plugin on jenkins and tried to access it. It says hadoop command not found. I can see the hadoop link on jenkins homepage and when i click on it. It shows :

```
To access this Hadoop, your hadoop-site.xml should contain the following entries:

<configuration>
  <property>
    <name>fs.default.name</name>
    <value>hdfs://hadoop-master:9000/</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>mapred.job.tracker</name>
    <value>hadoop-master:50040</value>
  </property>
</configuration>
```

Is there any way by which i can use hadoop on jenkins on the same port which is specified in my local-hadoop configuration.

Answer (score 0):

I have found one workaround for this problem.

We can define a node on Jenkins and can run the project on the local server where the entire setup is already in place. Doing ssh to the local machine... we will be able to access the Hadoop running on that local machine.